# Creating an error reset button in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button, error-handling

I'm trying to set a reset button to exit from an error status. I'd like the button to be in the main window not in a popup window.

I figure out a way to do it in the code below, but it's not possible to press the button because the window is frozen.

(The code is now updated after the comments received - still freezing)

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

err=0

def cycle():
        global err
        err=1
        lb1.configure(text="Error code xxx: press Step to continue")
        root.update()
        while err==1:
                time.sleep(0.1)
                continue
        time.sleep(2)
        lb1.configure(text="Error free")
        root.after(5000, cycle)  # reschedule event in 5 seconds 
        
def errReset():
        global err
        err=0

root=tk.Tk()
labels_array=[]

lb1=tk.Label(root,text="No error")
lb1.pack()
btn1=tk.Button(root,text="Step",command=errReset)
btn1.pack()

cycle()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what did you expect? when you call `cycle()` function it sets err to 1 and your while condition becomes True and keeps executing `time.sleep` again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem is that the value of `err` never changes in the `while err==1:` loop in the `cycle()` function. For one thing it's a local variable, but even declaring it `global` won't help because the `while` loop prevents anything else from running. That could be done in the popup window, but you didn't put the code for it in your question (it would need to be declared `global` there to affect what seen in the `cycle()` function).

Generally speaking things are hanging because there's an infinite-loop in `cycle()` which prevents the GUI's `mainloop()` from running which is what is causing your program freezes or "hangs".

Since you haven't include any popup window code in your question, about all I can do is show you (without writing code for that part myself) is give you a general idea of how things out to be done. In your real code you might want to always have `cycle()` running in the background, but in the code below it stops after the error variable gets set to zero (by some other part of the application).

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

RECYCLE = 1000  # How often to check global err state in milliseconds.

def cycle():
    if not err:  # Error cleared?
        lb1.configure(text="Error free")
    else:
        root.after(RECYCLE, cycle)  # Run again after delay

def errReset():
    global err
    err = 0

root = tk.Tk()

err = 1
lb1 = tk.Label(root, text=f"Error code {err}: click Step to clear")
lb1.pack()

btn1 = tk.Button(root, text="Step", command=errReset)
btn1.pack()

cycle()  # Begin periodically checking status of global err variable.
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: that's right thanks, I forgot it, but the window freeze problem is still there

Comment: Your other function has the same problem. I suggest your update the code in your question and fix these errors. Also just noticed that the `command=errReset()` is wrong because it calls the function when creating the `Button` (and sets the callback function to be called when it's clicked to the value `None`).

Comment: I updated the code with the suggested improvements

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer as much as I could—what I said initially wasn't correct.

Comment: effectively using the command root.after(RECYCLE, cycle) allows to avoid the freezing of the window, I tried to use it in my program, but still I need to understand better how to manage the various "after" commands in that. I have one after running periodically every 5 seconds that can generate an error and now  a new one that check the error every 2 seconds...

Comment: one additional question if possible: is it possible to assigned err variable directly in the button command without going through a def?